# VS Code - TypeScript configuration to serve AngularJS pages as well as run Jasmine unit and Protractor tests?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I've followed through with the [Naveen's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-DBzW2xlB0)  total newbie video tutorial on protractor testing with VS Code, which worked well for me, but he only shows building protractor tests against existing AngularJs websites, but doesn't demo how to host, serve and test my own AngularJS pages.  Naveen uses webdriver-manager in the video, but that didn't work for me use Live Server as well.

I am using the Live Server extension to serve pages and `node -r ts-node/register ./node_modules/.bin/jasmine' to run the tests Chrome/Live Server won't load the controller that includes my imported class.

The console error in Chrome is:

```
 angular.js:15570 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] 

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=FringeController
    at angular.js:99
    at angular.js:11680
    at ea (angular.js:10711)
    at p (angular.js:10496)
    at g (angular.js:9835)
    at g (angular.js:9838)
    at angular.js:9700
    at angular.js:1967
    at m.$eval (angular.js:19396)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:19495)
```

The js for my controller function generated by TypeScript is:

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports", "./fringe"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    const fringe_1 = require("./fringe");
    app.controller("FringeController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.fringe = new fringe_1.Fringe("SSI");
    });
});
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "AngularJSTestProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.6.57",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "angular": "^1.7.9",
    "jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "ts": "^0.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3",
    "typescriptnpm": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "umd",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "app",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:4444/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4444",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the one combo in tsconfig.json i didn't try was the one that works

```
 "target": "es6",
 "module": "amd"
```

No idea what that means but it works.